# Pages/DCTs not publishing in Tridion 2013

Tags: 2013

Pages/DCTs not publishing in Tridion 2013. We are getting the following message:

> Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703FA).

The cd_core log gives the following message:

> 2014-07-15 03:59:13,233 DEBUG EventDispatcher - TMA-AG-00000 No event to process
>   2014-07-15 03:59:13,654 DEBUG RollingStateRetriever - Unable to read transport state file, not adding to summary batch
>   2014-07-15 03:59:13,654 DEBUG RollingStateRetriever - Unable to read transport state file, not adding to summary batch

Not sure what is causing this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you can **edit your question** and **add** a bit more of a description of when this started happening, what has been done prior to this and what has been investigated/tried to fix this already? Adding the details of the error message (if available a stack trace might also help a lot ), and last did this system ever work, is it only publishing that is an issue or are there more issues?

Comment: Yes this system was working even yesterday. Not sure what changes were made as it is shared by many users from different locations. Yes we are facing problems when trying to publish items. Other functions are not affected yet. the cd_core log shows the following message: 2014-07-15 03:56:53,370 DEBUG RollingStateRetriever - Unable to read transport state file, not adding to summary batch

Comment: Can you see if you httpupload is still running.

In an internet browser of your choice, navigate to http://HOST:PORT/cd_upload/httpupload where HOST and PORT refer to the location of the HTTP Upload Web application.
The following text appears in your browser:

SDL Tridion HTTP Upload and Responder Servlet

Comment: Seems duplicate of http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/illegal-operation-attempted-on-a-registry-key-marked-for-deletion

Answer (score 2):

Usually this error comes due to some unexpected automatic update of Windows OS or even of JAVA.

You may check something like that has happened on the server.

The error is self explanatory that there is a registry key which have been marked for deletion but due to some reason it could not get deleted. I would suggest you to do following:

1. Stop IIS or App Pool
2. Stop all Tridion Services
3. Shut Down SDL Tridion Content Manager COM+ Application
4. Start all Tridion Services
5. Start IIS/App Pool
6. See if this resolved the error, if not Try Re-booting your Server

If it still does not resolve the issue, please see if there are error in Event Log and share here.